# Standard Currency field modification

Tags: multi-currency, currency

I recently enabled multiple currencies in my org.  I know that for Opportunities once the currency is set and there are line items that currency can not be modified.

Is this true for all objects?  I have couple of custom objects that have the currency field set on creation. After creation, the currency field is not being displayed on the page layout. I saw people suggesting adding a formula field to pull this information but I don't like this solution. I want the user to be able to view and modify the currency if needed directly form the record.

Please let me know if the below statements are correct:

1- Once record is created the currency field can only be updated via apex (can not be modified on the standard record page)

2- Standard currency field does not appear on page layouts even if the profile has full permissions.

If the above two statements are false. Please let me know if there are any workarounds for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For other objects, the currency field can be edited if the user has full permissions, the only fact is that this field is not visible on the detail page of a record.

It is only available in the edit mode.

You may have to modify your page layouts to include currency field.

When you are in the detail mode, you can identify the currency by looking at any currency type field. It will show three character ISO code along with amount.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can update the currency field just by clicking on edit if you have required permission.
2. Yes. For that we can create formula field to show the currency but which is not desired for you. You can vote for [this idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BrI9AAK) to have this feature in near future